# Building RPM package from cross-compiled binaries Go app tarballs

Tags: go, makefile, rpm, rpmbuild, bin

I'm trying to create my first RPM packages cross-compiled with Go.

Here is the Makefile which contains all the required information:

```
APPNAME?=helloworld
VERSION?=v1.0.0

APPANDVER := ${APPNAME}-$(VERSION)

# Build flags
LDFLAGS := -ldflags "-s -w -X=main.VERSION=$(VERSION)"

# Temporary directory for common files when creating tarballs
RELEASETMPDIR := $(shell mktemp -d -t ${APPNAME}-${VERSION}-release-XXXXXX)

# Cross-compile to these CPUs
# https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment
LINUX_ARCHS := amd64 arm arm64 ppc64 ppc64le

default: release-bin

main.go:
    @echo 'package main' > $@
    @echo 'import "fmt"' >> $@ 
    @echo '// Replaced with version when building' >> $@ 
    @echo 'var VERSION = "v0.0.0"' >> $@
    @echo 'func main() {' >> $@
    @echo '  fmt.Println("Hello, world!")' >> $@
    @echo '}' >> $@
    @go fmt $@

README.md:
    @echo 'This is a README for $(APPNAME) $(VERSION)' > $@
    @echo '$(APPNAME) simply prints "Hello, world!"' >> $@

LICENSE:
    @echo 'You can do what ever you want with $(APPNAME).' > $@
    @echo 'You have all the responsibility!' >> $@

# Build for all listed architectures
linux-build: main.go 
    @for arch in $(LINUX_ARCHS); do \
      echo "GNU/Linux build... $$arch"; \
      CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=$$arch go build $(LDFLAGS) -v -o ./bin/linux-$$arch/${APPNAME} . ; \
    done

# Copy common files used in binary tarball releases
copycommon: README.md LICENSE
    @echo "Copying common files to temporary release directory '$(RELEASETMPDIR)'.."
    @mkdir "$(RELEASETMPDIR)/bin"
    @cp -v "LICENSE" "$(RELEASETMPDIR)"
    @cp -v "README.md" "$(RELEASETMPDIR)"
    @mkdir --parents "$(PWD)/release/${VERSION}"

# Create binary release tarballs for each CPU architecture
compress-linux: linux-build
    @for arch in $(LINUX_ARCHS); do \
      echo "GNU/Linux tar... $$arch"; \
      cp -v "$(PWD)/bin/linux-$$arch/${APPNAME}" "$(RELEASETMPDIR)/bin"; \
      cd "$(RELEASETMPDIR)"; \
      tar --numeric-owner --owner=0 --group=0 -zcvf "$(PWD)/release/${VERSION}/$(APPANDVER)-linux-$$arch.tar.gz" . ; \
      rm "$(RELEASETMPDIR)/bin/${APPNAME}"; \
    done

# Move all to temporary directory and compress with common files
compress-everything: copycommon compress-linux
    @echo "$@ ..."
    rm -rf "$(RELEASETMPDIR)/*"

# Create tarballs which has common files and different bin/${APPNAME} per CPU architecture
release-bin: linux-build compress-everything
    @echo "release done..."

# Linux distributions
release-ldistros: ldistro-rpm
    @echo "Linux distros release done..."

release/linux/rpm:
    @mkdir --parents ./release/linux/rpm

# RPM spec file (probably wrong)
release/linux/rpm/package.spec: release/linux/rpm
    @echo 'Name: ${APPNAME}' > $@
    @echo 'Version: %{_version}' >> $@
    @echo 'Release: 1%{?dist}' >> $@
    @echo 'Summary: Hello world' >> $@
    @echo 'URL: https://example.org/${APPANDVER}/' >> $@
    @echo 'Group: Applications/Utilities' >> $@
    @echo 'License: Apache-2.0' >> $@
    @echo '%description' >> $@
    @echo '${APPNAME} is a command line program which prints "Hello, world!"' >> $@
    @echo '%setup -q' >> $@
    @echo '%clean' >> $@
    @echo '%files' >> $@
    @echo '%license /usr/share/licenses/%{NAME}/LICENSE' >> $@
    @echo '%doc /usr/share/doc/%{NAME}/README.md' >> $@
    @echo '/usr/bin/${APPNAME}' >> $@
    @echo '%install' >> $@
    @echo 'install -Dm755 "usr/bin/%{NAME}" -t "/usr/bin"' >> $@

# Create RPM package for each CPU architecture from tarballs (probably wrong)
ldistro-rpm: "release/linux/rpm/package.spec
    @for arch in $(LINUX_ARCHS); do \
      echo "Generating RPM... $$arch"; \
      tempdir=$$(mktemp -d -t $(APPANDVER)-rpm-XXXXXX) ; \
      echo "  >> Using temporary directory $$tempdir" ; \
      cd "$$tempdir" ; \
      mkdir --parents {SOURCES,RPMS,SPECS,SRPMS,BUILD,tmp} ; \
      cp "$(PWD)/release/linux/rpm/package.spec" "SPECS/${APPNAME}" ; \
      cd "BUILD"; \
      echo "  >> Extracting source binary package.." ; \
      tar -xzf "$(PWD)/release/${VERSION}/$(APPANDVER)-linux-$$arch.tar.gz" . ; \
      echo "  >> Generating directory structure in temp dir.." ; \
      mkdir --parents ./usr/bin/ ; \
      mv ./bin/${APPNAME} ./usr/bin/ ; \
      rm -rf ./bin ; \
      mkdir --parents ./usr/share/licenses/${APPNAME}/ ; \
      mv LICENSE ./usr/share/licenses/${APPNAME} ; \
      mkdir --parents ./usr/share/doc/${APPNAME}/ ; \
      mv README.md ./usr/share/doc/${APPNAME} ; \
      cd .. ; \
      echo "  >> Building RPM package.." ; \
      sudo rpmbuild -vv --nosignature --nodebuginfo --dbpath "$$tempdir" --root "$$tempdir" --buildroot "./BUILD" --target $$arch --define "_tmppath /tmp" --define "_topdir ." --define "_version ${VERSION}" --define "_buildhost localhost" --define "_rpmfilename $(APPANDVER)-$$arch.rpm" -bb "SPECS/${APPNAME}" && \
      rpm -qlp --info "./RPMS/$(APPANDVER)-$$arch.rpm" && \
      cp "./RPMS/$(APPANDVER)-$$arch.rpm" "$(PWD)/release/${VERSION}/" ; \
      echo "------------------------------------------------------------"; \
    done
```

Create `bin/$os-$cpuarch/$appname` binaries:

```
% make linux-build
```

Create the binary source tarballs to `release/$version/$appname-$version-$os-$cpuarch.tar.gz`:

```
% make compress-everything
```

Created file tree structure inside tarballs:

```
bin/$appname (different for each architecture)
LICENSE
README.md
```

This structure is locked in as there are also different OS tarballs too. Different OS build targets are removed in this minimized example for readability reasons.

Generate RPMs for each CPU architecture:

```
% make ldistro-rpm
```

The current problem is that during RPM build the actual executables are being installed to the running system. AFAIK this should not happen. What I might be missing from the spec file or `ldistro-rpm` target? Also some `rpmbuild` examples seemed to only use `-bb` parameter but I couldn't find examples or figure out how to modify the `spec` file so that could work. The `ldistro-rpm` target seems overly complicated. Should some commands be in the spec file's `%install`, `%prep`, etc? Can you somehow use the `Source0` in the `spec` file and point it to the tarball instead of generating the directory structure in the `ldistro-rpm` target?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm, it'll make it easier to build packages

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo 'install -Dm755 "usr/bin/%{NAME}" -t "/usr/bin"'
```

Is where you are installing to `/usr/bin` You should install to `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/bin` instead.

Comment: rpmbuilder errors on: `Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found: /usr/bin/helloworld` if `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` is added.

Comment: Then it needs to be added to the `%files` list.